# clear arraylist - android

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I have 2 lists after I finish fill list I added it to first list and clean the second list, the problem is: when I loop again after clear all items at second list that I added befor to first list, all items at first list changes
this is my code:

```
  JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Playlists");
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++){//for of playlist
                            JSONObject jsonItem = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String playlistTitle =  jsonItem.getString("ListTitle");
                            JSONArray listItems = jsonItem.getJSONArray("ListItems");//for of groups
                            for(int j = 0; j < listItems.length(); j++){//for of items
                                JSONObject objItem = listItems.getJSONObject(j);
                                ListItem item = new ListItem(objItem.getString("Title"), objItem.getString("link"), objItem.getString("thumb"));
                                mListItems.add(item);
                            }
                            mPlaylistItems.add(new Playlist(playlistTitle, mListItems));
                            mListItems.clear();
                        }
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're adding `mListItems` by reference to `mPlaylistItems`. Looking at your implementation clearing is unnecessary and can/should just be removed.

Comment: Happy to help :)